# jquery addClass not finding id specific class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a class applied to only an ID but when I use addClass it doesnt find the css class when its applied to the element. Am I adding it wrong since the js is working and adding the class, the class is just not found?

CSS

```
#responsive-menu-toggle {
  height: 3.125em;
  width: 3.125em;
  border: none;
  background: url("img/menu.svg") no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.25em;
  right: 1.25em; 
}
#responsive-menu-toggle .menu-toggle-active {
    background: url("img/menu-close.svg") no-repeat; 
}
```

JS

```
$('#responsive-menu-toggle').click(function(event) {
    $('#page').toggleClass('menu-open');
    $('.mobile-menu').toggleClass('mobile-menu-open');
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-toggle-active');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove space between `#responsive-menu-toggle .menu-toggle-active` - 
if there is space in selector, it searches for children elements with this class INSIDE element with given id, instead of element with this id AND class.

Comment: Perfect. Actually that was compiled Sass. I forgot to nest the class with an `&` sign.